# Flutter: How to properly read a field from a JSON?

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

Please check the below flutter code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'dart:io';


class UserService with ChangeNotifier {
  NavLinks _navLinks = NavLinks();
  late User _user;

  Future<int> saveUser(User user, String authToken) async {
    print(convert.json.encode(user.toJson()));
    int responsetag = 0;
    try {
      await http.post(Uri.parse(_navLinks.saveUser()),
          body: convert.json.encode(user.toJson()),
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $authToken"
          }).then((http.Response response) {
        final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

        print("RESPONSE: " + response.body);
        print("STATUS CODE: " + statusCode.toString());

        if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400) {
          throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
        } else {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

          responsetag = int.parse(data["insertId"]);
        }
      });

      return responsetag;
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
}
```

Here i need to extract the `insertId`, convert it to an int and pass over. But I always end up with error `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: I don't think the error is from here, where are u using this number? the error comes from UI which I think is a Text widget somewhere. share that code.

Comment: @Benyamin: Well, it is used in a single code line, nothing but this `int userid = await userService.saveUser(user, authToken);`

Comment: This error is from UI which means you have passed an integer value to a widget expecting a string value and u should use toString() method on that, error is from UI.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data/response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code `data["insertId"]` should be a String.

if `data["insertId"]` is a String,

```dart
responsetag = int.parse(data["insertId"]);
```

if `data["insertId"]` is an int,

```dart
responsetag = data["insertId"];
```

Comment: Thank you. You addressed the point. It was an int so the second code line did work

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
responsetag = int.parse(data["insertId"]);
```

To this

```
responsetag = int.parse(data["insertId"].toString());
```